Can I make car starter cables out of standard appliance cables?
Good quality starter cables are expensive. That's a fact, no way around it.
I want to keep some in my trunk for emergencies.
I looked around and saw some rated for 600 A and 1200 A.
Why can't I make cables from stuff laying around?
A standard appliance cable is rated: 240 V@15 A.
Well this would make a 12 V@300 A.
And each cable has 3 wires in it that can be wired in parallel.
So using two cables a 900 A rated starter cables can be made from stuff we all have laying around.
It can't be as simple as that can it?
I'm surely missing something or starter cables won't be as thick as they are.

That's not how voltage and current ratings work.

If you had a 12V drop @ 300A  how much voltage would you have left from 14.2 ;)  You can get 3ft of AWG4 pairs red/black for $33 on amazon ok?

Yes of course cost itself isn't a show stopper as much as price/value if it's as easy as i thought, but of course it's not or everyone would do this and i couldn't find any others doing this so i wanted a deeper understanding of the reasons at work, people here answered very nicely to sum up the reasons why jumper cables are so over-rated compared to appliance cables, amazing response for my first post, thanks!

I thought starter cables is a thing of the past? Modern car batteries come with all manner of surrounding electronics... I would hesitate to hook up starter cables to that. Frying some ECU just to jump start some battery would get expensive.

@Lundin Modern car batteries come with all manner of surrounding electronics ... car batteries do not contain electronics ... you di not connect jumper cables to electronics

@jsotola You do not connect jumper cables to modern car batteries. My car comes with two specific jump/charge points. It is to ensure current flows through the metering arrangement for proper battery SoC and health estimation, needed due
to auto start-stop safety.

An important factor that doesn't seem to be covered so far is that in most cases when a car battery is jump started the vehicle's own battery is charged by the jumpstarter and then used for the actual starting. The jumpstart cables themselves often do not carry a significant portion of the current that is used in the actual starting action. As a consequence you can use quite low gauge wires to transfer energy from the jumpstarter into the vehicles battery and then the vehicle starts on its own battery. The above claim is liable to be met with some  scepticism but this  is often how it works.

Since @RussellMcMahon saved me the work of explaining the most common use case, I will contribute one more: If it's a hybrid vehicle (Prius in particular) the "jump" only needs to supply power to get the vehicle "booted".  Once the main battery cuts in, the car powers itself.   And you can make (and I have) a cheap "jumper-cable-shaped-object" for that use.  The draw is on the order of tens of amps for about 3 seconds.

@RussellMcMahon, That probably explains how I was able to jump start my Honda Pilot yesterday with this piece of ****: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0B6HTHTJP/ [P.S., Probably not a freak occurence because I used the same piece of **** to jump start my ski boat a few months earlier. I wonder how many more "jumps" I can get out of it before it bursts into flame.]

@SolomonSlow Some day I'd like to test the actual current such things provide. It's certainly vastly below what is claimed. No surprise. I've started a 'just flat enough to refuse to start' van (wurra wurra ... click click click ) with 2 x 3Ah x 6V LA batteries all connected with bell wire. || In the "looked like a magician" class :-) : Closing time at an Aluminium extrusions etc seller. A car would not start. Whoops - no jumper leads. I looked in their scrap bin and got 3 or 4 lengths of Al extrusion. Joined two batteries with people holding sections touching. Wait a few minutes. Success :-).

Current rating and voltage rating of a cable are two completely different things.
You cannot translate 240V/15A rating into 12V/300A. The 240V/15A rating is capable of 15A no matter what voltage you throw at it (somewhat simplified, it may be worse at low voltage since the voltage drop will have a larger impact).
The voltage rating is related to the insulation of the cable. The current rating is (mostly) related to the wire thickness.
So you need 300A rated cables in order to do 300A. Not 15A rated cables.

Said another way: a wire is just a fuse waiting for too much current. It's why operating a circular saw using a lamp cord extension cord (16awg or smaller wire) is a really bad idea.

Technically the OP is still correct that you could make it from things hanging around. If you have 120 regular appliance cables hanging around, you absolutely can make a pair of 900A starter cables with 60 in parallel. With the minor inconvenience that the bundle of cables would be the size of your leg, and assuming you have 120 appliance cables spare in the first place. :)

@Graham And the minor inconvenience that if the resistance of any of those 120 cables was slightly lower than the others, they would pass disproportionately higher current and possibly melt.

@TripeHound Setting fire to the idiot's car if they try this should be seen as a feature, not a bug. ;)

@TripeHound: True, though when that cable heats up, its resistance will increase, so (in principle at least) it can reach an equilibrium where current is relatively balanced.

TripeHound's comment shows how to identify someone who knows the theory but not the practice.

Re "may be worse at low voltage since the voltage drop will have a larger impact)": No. The same voltage drop will always have the same impact. Higher voltage at the ends of the cable means higher voltage drop, necessarily (it is the voltage drop!), with larger "impact", namely current, and quadratically more electrical power/watts/heat.

@psmears As opposed to semiconductors which decrease resistance when heated beyond a point so they reach "equilibrium" with all current going through a tiny spot that burns/melts out.  The dreaded "secondary breakdown" of power transistors.

@Graham, you'd only need 20 appliance cables for each jump lead, since each one has three 15A conductors which you can use.  Subject to all the other problems, of course.

@user107063: Yes indeed - and why putting LEDs in parallel is a bad idea.

@TobySpeight Good catch - you're right. Only a bundle of cables the size of your arm, then.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica What I was thinking of was the fact that for 240V a 10V drop is usually no issue for the load. But at 12V the same 10V drop will make the car not start.

@Klas-Kenny Ah, yes, that is correct.

@Klas-Kenny's answer is correct. The cables don't know anything about what voltage they're at until the insulation voltage is exceeded and then they start to break down. The wire is a resistor and will heat up with current - and worse - it's with the square of the current.
For the power equation you made the mistake of using the load voltage instead of the voltage drop along the cable.
The easier way to calculate for cable power losses is to use a variation of the power equation, \$ P = VI = (IR)I = I^2R \$. Remember that power loss in the cable will be dissipated as heat, heating the wires and melting the insulation. Also, with smaller diameter wires the voltage drop will be so high that there won't be enough voltage at the car you're trying to start. There are many online calculators which will help you size cables and calculate voltage drop.

Aside from the cable issues, which have been amply covered in the other answers, a major concern for high current wiring is that the terminations (typically to large crocodile clips in the case of jumper cables) are critical.  A poor termination will result in a significant voltage drop and rapid heating.  An effective joint calls for a terminal that’s designed for the size of cable being used and the proper tools - often a crimping tool.  A pair of pliers won’t be sufficient.

You can buy replacement jumper cable clamps from any auto parts store for ~$15. Make sure they're jumper clamps and not the lower capacity charger clamps.

Which is why cheap jumper cables often have melted insulation on the clips after a few uses (at the cable end of the clip, not the battery terminal end, at least is you ensure they've made good contact)

My homemade jumpers I made 30 years ago work much better than any cheapo jumper cable as demonstrated by a few jumps for myself and probably a couple dozen jumps for fellow employees. People unfamiliar with these jumpers are surprised how well they work. They don't need to cost that much. Be sure to rinse the clips with water to remove acid particles after jumping.
My construction:

SO 6/2 cable (pair of #6 AWG conductors, about 4.1 mm dia solid wire equivalent) with stranded conductors. The trick here is the conductors are copper, no copper clad aluminum that you find in cheapo cables.
Mueller BU-41A clips (about 7 USD each).
#12 AWG (about 2.0 mm dia solid wire equivalent) stranded hookup wire to provide a jumper between the two halves of the clips.
Total cable length, including clips: 4 m (apx 13 feet).
All joints soldered which is very helpful to reduce resistance.


My homemade jumper cables. Photo credits: self
I only had to pay for the clips as the wire was scrap from work.

tl; dr: no, you can't make jumper cables out of appliance wires.
What are you missing? You're confusing power (which is voltage * current) and current by itself. When it comes to wire, it's current that sets the required. This is because wire has resistance; it generates heat when current passes through it (W = I²R). See that I² term? That's what gets you.
Let's look at your example. 240V @ 15A is the same power as 12V @ 300A. You're correct on that point. But, try pushing 300A of current through #12ga (such as you would find on an appliance) for the same equivalent power and I guarantee it will fry in short order. That's because typical #12ga wire is rated for only 20A; its resistance will be far too high for 300A, resulting in much heating and rapid, fiery failure.
How much fire? #12ga wire has a resistance of about 0.0016 ohms/ft. (reference). Let's say we have a wire that's 10 feet long. When pushing 300A through that wire, the power that will be shed in that wire will be:

P = I²·R
P = 300A ✕ 300A ✕ (10' ✕ .0016 ohm) = 1440W, in each wire, so 2880W total.

Then there's the voltage drop:

V = I·R
V = 300A ✕ (10 ✕ .0016) = 4.8V, again in each wire, so 9.6V

In other words, for wires to survive, let alone deliver useful voltage and current, they need to be sized for the worst-case current they're expected to handle. There's a made-up word electricians and engineers use for this: ampacity, which is, unsurprisingly, a portmanteau of amperage+capacity. Simply stated, ampacity is how much current a wire can carry without being damaged by heat, given some factors like ambient temperature, insulation type, ventilation, and so forth.
This is especially true of jumper cables, which need to be sized large enough (have enough ampacity) to handle not only charging current (10-50A or so) but also possibly hundreds of amps of cranking current, and be able to do this without excessive IR drop let alone instantly melting.
On the face of it, #12ga isn't going to cut it. Not enough ampacity. What to do then?
The answer for jumper cables is use lots of finely stranded copper, terminated with clamps that won't melt while carrying those big cranking currents. Furthermore, the longer the cable, the heavier its wire gauge needs to be to reduce its voltage drop.
As a baseline, typical automotive jumper cables will be constructed of thicker #6ga or #4ga finely stranded wire. More here: https://mechanicbase.com/electric/what-size-of-jumper-cables-to-carry/ This kind of wire is flexible yet can handle the current.
Let's see how 10 feet of #6ga performs at 300A compared to our fiery failure we had with #12ga:

P = 300A ✕ 300A ✕ (10' ✕ .0004 ohm) = 360W each wire, 720W total
V = 300A ✕ (10' ✕ .0004 ohm) = 1.2V each wire, 2.4V total

And #4ga:

P = 300A ✕ 300A ✕ (10' ✕ .00025 ohm) = 225W each wire, 450 total
V = 300A ✕ (10' ✕ .00025 ohm) = 0.75V each wire, 1.25V total

Much better. There's still some IR drop and some heating, but they work. For a price, though: the large amount of copper required to do the job that makes jumper cables kind of costly.
A side note. A 'jump box' can use smaller cables (but still bigger than #12ga) because the wires are shorter, and thus have less IR drop to contend with. One of these is a good option to carry in your trunk instead of cables (and it's what most tow truck drivers carry.) The ones marketed today use Li-ion batteries and retain their charge for a long time.
A tip when using either cables or a jump box. After connecting things, let the drained battery charge up a bit, ideally for a few minutes. Once the battery has some charge on it, it too will be able to deliver some current to the starter in addition to the cables or box. If that battery is dead-dead and vehicle still won't crank, it's time for a fresh battery.

Super-Cap jump boxes are also available. Downside is having to charge the unit before use which can take 5 or more minutes. Li-ion units need periodic charging and they pose a potentially hazardous risk when stored in a hot car. The Li-ion unit I have never worked as it faulted when trying to jump-start a small car on multiple occasions.

Your "tip" at the end is in fact how jumper cables are meant to be used: They are intended to allow the running car to charge the dead car's battery. As such, they only need to carry the output current of the alternator for any length of time, not the load current of the starter. If the battery is too dead to take any charge at all, you simply won't be able to start the car. The contact resistance, etc. of the jumper cables won't allow the necessary current to flow.

A car starter cable will not support the current you need to direct start even a puny 25hp tractor.  When the clamps start glowing, it may be time to stop.

@DaveTweed in practice it's both - so you top up the weak battery for a few minutes (the longer the better) then start with the strong battery + alternator of the helper vehicle in parallel with the weak, but no longer totally flat,  battery.  The top-up time can reduce to under a minute if you're in a real rush and it will still work if the engine turns over quickly

I will put some color in for why you are seeing jumper cables that look a lot thinner than you'd expect for the amount of current the manufacturer says they'll take:
The current ratings are made up
Well maybe not made up, but they are shall we say optimistic. I'm looking at a set of 4 AWG cables right now that say they're rated for 600A at 60C, which I assume is the temp rating of the PVC insulation. Ampacity tables put 4 AWG copper-coated aluminum wires at 55A for 60-degree rated wire. But ampacity tables are conservative because they are meant to be relied upon for safety and to prevent your house from burning down. When jumper cables fail, the insulation just melts off and you find a new pair.
4 AWG is also on the large side for consumer grade jumper cables. Take a look at the termination into the clamps and you'll see how much of the diameter of the wire is cheap PVC instead of more expensive metal.

I would hazard a guess that the current ratings are based on say a 10 to 30-second start, similar to cold-cranking-amps. There's no point looking at six-hour ratings for cables not expected to serve for more than a minute.

:) I would guess that to be generous the rated current would drop about 13 V, on each of the cables, not including the connection resistance. Your dollar store 300 A cables have a quarter inch of cheap grey plastic under the red coating and then a 12 awg aluminium/iron/copper core. Pair that with clamp teeth thinner that a tin can, loosely folded over the wires in a sort of crimp, one jaw only...

You have to consider two things- the current rating of the wire and the voltage drop over the length of the cables. 3 15A wires in parallel would make about a 40A wire (two are supposed to work in parallel and the third does not normally conduct, but they are closely coupled.
Light duty jumper cables for automotive use are typically something like AWG 6 and 12' or 16'. That's a bit more than  13mm^2 cross sectional area. AWG 6 single conductor wire (stranded) can be purchased from Home Depot type places, I see a price of $1.42/foot so a 16' pair would be $45 for the wire. Plus you need the clamps and some means of crimping them. You can get black by the foot, but red only comes in hanks of 100' for $127. Cheap jumper cables may use aluminum wire rather than copper. Ampacity for 90°C AWG 6 wire is given as 75A, but for brief cranking they will tend not to melt if the crimps are good.
Here's an example of heavy-duty well-made copper jumper cables:

As you can see the gauge generally increases as the length does. 1/0 90°C has an ampacity of 170A.
The jumper companies are rating the wire at about 40%-60% of fusing current (the current where the copper itself melts). A high percentage for the lighter duty cables.
Now if we take two pieces of your appliance wire (say it is AWG 14/3 - a reasonably well-made one) and parallel all three wires, and use two of them not bundled together you'd get a ~40A ampacity, an equivalent 'rating' of about 250A and it would probably be usable as an extra-light duty cable if you kept the length reasonably short, like 10'/3m. A 10' cable would have a resistance of about 17mΩ so it would drop 4V or so at 250A. I'd rather have the heavy duty one on a cold winter day, but better the crummy one than nothing, worst case it could allow the dead battery to charge enough to help out.
And if you were to use 4 runs of such cable- 6 wires in parallel for each side- you'd be firmly in the light-duty jumper cable territory.

@MrGerber They are rated at 15A per conductor with only two conductors working (ground does not normally conduct). The permissible rating goes down with bundled wires depending on how many are conducting because they heat each other and the insulation has a fixed temperature rating. Therefore you shouldn't assume you'll get 3x the rating with 3 conductors in parallel. See, for example, this document, or refer to the original FAA document 43.13-1B or equivalent in other countries.

Electricians and many others use simplified methods that incorporate a large safety factor and thus can safely ignore bundling, altitude and other factors that become important in fields where the design has to be right. I didn't want to get too technical with the steady-state ratings since they don't really apply in this kind of cranking application, but there is more information available for those who are interested.

@MrGerber The Ground wire does not normally conduct 15A in a 15A power cord. It conducts 0A, unless something is very wrong.

Nevermind......
